# Android share on facebook via what?

Tags: android

I have successfully built my android app to support sharing on facebook. The problem is when someone shares something there is a link that facebook adds for me automatically that says shared via "my app name". If I click on it, a error occurs on facebook *note this link is usually on facebook and says shared via mobile or shared via android

error code-
The page you requested was not found.
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.

How can i fix this link or where do i set it? 
*I think this may be set on the settings on facebook but am unsure

my code to share comment

```
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });
```

Comment: How did you support Facebook sharing? Did you use some library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the facebook android API, you should do this

```
       private Facebook mFacebook; 
       private String mMessageToPost; 
        ...  
       function postToWall(urMessageAndLink)
       {
          Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
          parameters.putString("message", urMessageAndLink);
          parameters.putString("description", theTopic);
          facebook.request("xx");
          String response = mFacebook.request("xx/feed", parameters, "POST");
       }



      facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                if (mMessageToPost != null) {
                    postToWall(mMessageToPost);
                }
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                showToast("Error!!");
                finish();
            }

            public void onError(DialogError error) {
                showToast("Error!!");
                finish();
            }

            public void onCancel() {
                showToast("Facebook sharing cancelled!");
                finish();
            }
}
```

You can also use the android share API (but that requires theuser to have the facebook app, the share API opens a dialog box to choose any existing app that supports sharing)

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            String textMsg = "http://the.link.you.want.to.send";
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textMsg);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, aTitle));
```

Comment: how would I integrate your first idea into this code, as it seems the facebook api does the work for me. How can I modify it